# Tag property is null when called in Command

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, command

**XAML**

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:ReturnsUserControl.GetValueCommand}"
                    Executed="ExecutedGetValueCommand"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteGetValueCommand" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
<TextBox x:Name="txtExchangeQuantity" />
<Button Content="Add"
        Tag="{Binding ProductBarcode}"
        Command="{x:Static local:ReturnsUserControl.GetValueCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtExchangeQuantity}"/>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public static RoutedCommand GetValueCommand = new RoutedCommand();
private void ExecutedGetValueCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (sender) as Button;
    MessageBox.Show(b.Tag.ToString());
}
private void CanExecuteGetValueCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

When I clicked the button, I receive a `NullException` because apparently the `Tag`'s value is null, but I'm sure that the `Tag` has a value. So how can I get the `Tag`'s value using `Command`?

Here's what I used to check if the `Tag` has something:

```
private void SampleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btnSelect = sender as Button;
    string barcode = btnSelect.Tag.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(barcode);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the `ProductBarcode` binding actually works? The following sample code certainly works. Please refer to it.

```
private void ExecutedGetValueCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = e.OriginalSource as Button;
    MessageBox.Show(btn.Tag.ToString());
}
```

---

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:ReturnsUserControl.GetValueCommand}"
                    Executed="ExecutedGetValueCommand"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteGetValueCommand" />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtExchangeQuantity" />
        <Button Content="Add"
                        Tag="tag..."
                        Command="{x:Static local:ReturnsUserControl.GetValueCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtExchangeQuantity}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Note that I use the `OriginalSource` property of the `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs`.